# Getting tax value to calculate once state is selected

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm attempting to add sales tax logic to my site and I have a pretty good start except I am running into a couple of issues.

1. The largest issue is the tax value isn't being recognized. I have all of my other values like price, shipping cost, etc in a database and I'm storing the values with a session. So, they pull from that. When I select a state, the value isn't being added to my calculations, so I'm not sure how to do that.
2. I'm not sure how to make the equation to not calculate tax price if there is not any. I'm only calculating tax for one state like:

   ```
   $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
   $tax_price += $base_price * $taxvalue[''];

   $tax_price - $base_price;
   ```

   For example:

   base_cost = $10

   tax_value = $1.065

   So $10 * $1.065 -$10 = tax

So if the customer chooses any other state other than my tax state it would subtract the price cost in the tax spot.

I obviously haven't included all of the states, but I really need to see what I can do to get the tax value added in once the state is selected.

```
<?php               
            $base_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];


            }
            $tax_price += $base_price * $taxvalue[''];
            $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;
}
$taxvalue['Ohio'] = 1.065;
$taxvalue['Virginia'] = 1;
?>
```

The form part:

```
<label for="state">State</label>
<select type="text" class="mediuminputbar preview" id="ShipTostate" data-copy="#confirmstate" name="ShipTostate" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->state); ?>" required>
    <option value=''>Select a State</option>
<?php
foreach($taxvalue as $key => $val) {
    echo "<option value='$val'>$key</option>/n";
}   
?>
</select>
```

With the code I just posted, the name of the state doesn't carry forward, only the value does. Is there any way I can change this so the state's name goes through in certain instances and then the value goes through in others?

For instance when I send the order I need the states name for shipping info etc. Then I need the tax value in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Its because html select input only sends one value. Here if you want to send name of state, create a separate input to select state or join both values.

This is the line that causes problem

```
echo "<option value='$val'>$key</option>/n";
```

Change that to something that carries both values. use a special character to join both name of state and value. Then explode that value with php `exlode()` function. Thus you get name of state and its value easily.

Example

```
echo "<option value='$val^$key'>$key</option>/n";
```

See above example, I joined $val and $key with special character "^".now you will get both state and value in php. Explode this with special character "^".